# Signal detection in the presence of both theoretical and experimental uncertainty

Tags: forecasting, signal-detection

I am wondering what the best way to go about the following situation is. I will try to frame it in a clear way but please leave a comment if something can be clarified. I suspect this type of thing is a general problem encountered so I will strip away details of my specific application.

Suppose there is a quantity $C(x)$, where $x$ is some independent variable, which under a null hypothesis has a certain distribution that I have access to. That is to say, I can generate samples of $C(x)$ and compute things like pointwise confidence intervals, etc. Suppose as well that I have forecasted errors for an upcoming experiment that is set to measure $C(x)$, i.e. I have some forecasted variance at each $x$ that tells me how tightly this experiment may measure $C(x)$.

My problem is that I want to see how well this experiment, with its forecasted errors,  will be able to distinguish between $C(x)$ being drawn from its distribution under the null hypothesis vs some other distribution (that I can also sample from).

To start, what I have tried is this. First, I transform $C(x)$ to something distributed around 0 at each $x$ by subtracting the mean of the null hypothesis distribution, specifically I form the quantity $$\Delta(x) = \frac{C(x) - \bar{C}(x)}{\bar{C}(x)}$$
Now, I have a distribution for $\Delta$ that is spread around 0 at each $x$. This is where I am unsure how to proceed. What I have done as a first pass is to sample from my alternative distribution, subtract the same mean and divide as before, to form a quantity $\Delta'(x)$. I want to test how well my upcoming experiment will be able to tell if $\Delta'(x)$ is drawn from the same distribution as $\Delta(x)$ under the null hypothesis. Here is a picture which sort of illustrates what I mean so far:
[image]

Here, the gray bands are the distribution for $\Delta(x)$ I would expect under the null hypothesis, the red line is $\Delta'(x)$, and the error bars are binned versions of my forecasted errors. If instead of a distribution I had a definite prediction for $C(x)$ under the null hypothesis, then the situation would be more clear to me. But given the theoretical uncertainty indicated by gray bands and experimental uncertainty given by the error bars, I am less clear on how to proceed. My intuition is that I will need to consider some type of convolution of the two errors but other than that I am a bit lost.